# GET request from google drive api error

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm working on a server run with node that needs to get a file from google drive.

Is there anything blatantly wrong that I'm doing here?

```
drive.files.get({
    fileId: id,
    alt: 'media',
    auth: oauth2Client
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log('Error in download');
    else  deferred.resolve(data);
  });
```

Given that drive is require('googleapis').drive('v2'), oauth2Client is a valid oauth client and id is the id of the file.

Testing with the google api playground shows that making a get request with the options id, media, and with a new oauth2Client works, but in the application there's an error. I'm unable to see this error, as trying to console.log it crashes node with "illegal access" (looking this up on stackoverflow and the google forums tells me this error is not high priority).

Comment: check this link https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-nodejs.Are you able to run the sample code in the above link?

Comment: Yes. Things like insert and delete work fine, as does get with the default alt (json), but specifying alt as 'media' breaks it.

Comment: Which type of file are you giving in the request when giving alt=media. YOu have to give only media files. I tried with "png" file and with alt=media, it worked fine with response code 200